# Calling a variable that has been set inside a foreach - powershell

Tags: powershell

Very basic question i'm sorry but I'm sure I had this down before. I want to just know how I can access the variable from inside a `foreach`. For example in this simple code, it just echos $username but not the exact name i'm after...however if you put echo `$user` it looks like it can read the `foreach` and the csv.

```
add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010

$ExSession = New-PSSession –ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange –ConnectionUri http://dlonsexh05.server.local/PowerShell/ –Authentication Kerberos

import-PSSession $Exsession -AllowClobber

$users= import-csv 'C:\Surface Pro\users.csv'

foreach ($user in $users){

$duedate = $user.DueDate
$Username = $user.Name
$email = $user.EmailAddress


$smtpServer = "dlonsexh05.server.local"
$smtpFrom = "helpdesk@server.com"
$smtpTo = $email
$messageSubject = "$username your laptop is due back on $duedate"
$SMTPPort = "587"



$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpfrom, $smtpto
$message.Subject = $messageSubject

$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($message)
Remove-PSSession $Exsession

break

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you're looping through everything and *then* displaying the `$username`, so you're always going to display the last one.

If you move the `echo` to inside the loop, you'll display all of them:

```
$users= import-csv 'C:\Surface Pro\users.csv'
foreach ($user in $users){
    $username = $user.Name
    echo $username
}
```

If you want a specific one, you need code to filter them, so use a `if` statement somewhere, or filter with `Where-Object`; it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks briantist. I'd like to declare a load of variables inside that CSV and then use them later on. For example $email = $User.email ...then outside the loop i'd like to use it in a function or something similar to send an email to everyone in the email column of the csv. Do I have to put all of my SMTP code inside the loop??

Comment: @DanielGripton well, yes. Each loop iteration is giving you one row of the CSV, so the code you want to run against _each row_ should be inside the loop.

Comment: Ok this is tricky! I've put the code inside , it sends the emails to each email address in the CSV but sends about 5 more blank ones. If I do a break it only sends to the top one. I'd like it to work throigh the CSV and then stop once its finished all of the email addresses. Heres the code!